# How to duplicate records for Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a couple of Ecto records. But I want to duplicate them (make them 100 times bigger) to play with big amount of records. How can I do that via ecto mechanisms?

Comment: You probably want https://github.com/thoughtbot/ex_machina.

Comment: I don't want to use ex_machina outside of `test` env, thanks :P

Comment: Dummy solution: loop through some range with `Repo.insert`, but propably you thought about it already.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it. Maybe, there is an undiscovered thing like rails's `dup` in ecto?

Answer (score 6):

You can replicate `dup` by simply removing the id key from the record:

```
for n <- (0..10), do: User |> Repo.get(record_id) |> Map.delete(:id) |> Repo.insert
```

Although that won't work if you have unique keys... that would leave you needing to populate the struct yourself:

```
def spawn_records(line_numbers) do
  for line <- line_numbers do
    %User{first_name: "Tyrone", last_name: "Shoelaces#{line}"} |> Repo.insert
  end
end
```

If you're thinking of that second answer I'd echo Dogbert and recommend using ex_machina in dev.

Comment: I got an error `** (KeyError) key :id not found` trying this trick trying this with Ecto 3.4 today, but using `Map.put(:id, nil)` instead works.

Answer (score 5):

After I stripped the :id, I ran into an issue while attempting to insert because I didn't preload my associations.  I shouldn't have to do that if I'm just duplicating the record, so I came up with this method.  This assumes you have your schema's required and optional fields defined as constants in your module:

```
@required_fields [:id, :name, :association_id]
@optional_fields [:other_field]

def duplicate(record) do
  dup = Map.take(record, @required_fields ++ @optional_fields)

  changeset(%YourModule{}, dup)
  |> Repo.insert!
end
```

Comment: TIL that Ecto 2 provides a __schema__ on the schema module which provide runtime introspection of the schema https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-reflection, so you could do things like `fields = __MODULE__.__schema__(:fields)`